# Lambda function producing old results after request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am writing a script to scrap a certain webpage.
For the architecture it is a serverless function which scrapes the certain page every minute, so that we are notified as soon as possible about changes.

My problem is that the result of the query says no new entry was found, only old ones, which it doesn't report.

Today there is another entry which is new so I should have gotten a report about it.

When I execute the function manually it does actually work and report it. When I removed the entry, it still didn't report it automatically from AWS.

After doing some debugging I noticed that on the client side, the result from a request is the new version of the web page.
On AWS Lambda, I still get the old result of the page.

Client-side commands tried (both work)

- `node-debug sls function run example/functionname`
- `sls function run example/functionname`

The server does run the function entirely and doesn't report any errors in cloudwatch. Personally I started to think that the problem was related to caching, although that doesn't exist there(right?).

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

The line that gets the old version: 
 `request(url, function (error, response, html) {`

Example code: 
(async part)
(get= get the html)
(checkLogged = if already reported)(doLog = logs if not reported)

```
export const respond = (event, cb) => {
  async.waterfall([
    get,
    checkLogged,
    doLog
  ], cb);    
};
```

Code that check for all entries

```
const get = (cb) => {
    const url = 'http://www.xxx.be/en/xxx/xxx/xxx';
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            //look for entries
        }
        else{
            return cb(new Error('couldn\'t load xxx'));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more code that shows the skeleton of the whole lambda function - could be the way that the code is structured and the order that things are run.

Comment: I'll add that now, thx for the response

Comment: 4 hours after the initial post of the new entry the lambda script fnally picked it up. Does this help you?

Comment: I had an issue similar to this.

I write an origiana function in Node.js, let's call it FunctionA ... then I add more code, let's call that FunctionB, made 100% sure I saved it and tested it form the app....

This is all done at work on my laptop. I then come home open the function again on my desktop and it's back to FunctionA... Can't find any reason for this...